# Login in Javascript without a backend server

Tags: javascript, json, api, authentication

**How can I fetch and send data without a backend server?**

I have taken on as a project to create a login with JavaScript. Does it make sense to create my own JSON file? Where do I store data with using localstorage?

Comment: I hope you know that if it's going to be browser-only then it's 100% unsecure as it can be seen by anyone with some knowledge of the F12 key.

Comment: Well it can't be done, you need a server to login

Comment: Login to what? If there's no backend server, what is it doing that needs a login?

Comment: it is not a real login, it is a simple project where I try to understand fetch

Comment: Did you mean to write "with**out** using localstorage"?

Comment: Related (might be a duplicate?) https://stackoverflow.com/q/55754473/125981  will give you a bit to clarify and add some details as to why NOT.  Also related https://stackoverflow.com/q/19902538/125981

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure if you store passwords on the client side, without authentication from the backend, then the client can just search to find the password stored on their side. If you don't care about that, you can store their data as far as I know, in cookies or on their local storage.